# libGDX timer - error in schedule

Tags: java, arrays, timer, libgdx, timertask

I am attempting to spawn an object after a 1 second delay, every 2 seconds. My attempts, however, result in the object spawning after a 1 second delay, but then at an exceptionally fast past (i.e. much more frequently than every 2 seconds). I cannot figure out why my timer task is spawning the objects so close together. Any help would be great, thanks.

```
private Array<Rectangle> spacebars;

public void spawnSpacebar() 
{
spacebar = new Rectangle();
spacebar.x = 800;             
spacebar.y = MathUtils.random(0, 480-64);
spacebar.width = 64;
spacebar.height = 64;
spacebars.add(spacebar);
}

Timer.schedule(new Task()
{@Override
public void run() 
  {
  spawnSpacebar();
  }
}
, 1  // (delay)
, 2  // (every x seconds)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: I realized after writing this answer that you're trying to use the LibGDX Timer class. In that case, make sure you're using LibGDX Timer and not the java.util.Timer

Looks like the parameters for schedule() are in milliseconds. From the java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29):

public void schedule(TimerTask task,
            long delay,
            long period)

Parameters:
    task - task to be scheduled.
    delay - delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed.
    period - time in milliseconds between successive task executions.

So try passing 1000 and 2000 instead of 1 and 2.

Comment: Hi Barodapride - I am definitely using the LibGDX Timer class. I also tried passing 1000 and 2000 instead of 1 and 2, which did not work. Just to confirm, my delay seems to be working fine, but any number I pass to "every x seconds" seems to result in the same extremely fast spawn rate. An interesting point: when passing 2 to "every x seconds", the spawn rate actually increases quite quickly, from what was already a very fast pace. By comparison, when passing 2000 to "every x second", the spawn rate does not seem to increase as quickly, but spawns at about the same starting pace as passing 2.

Comment: Are you sure the Timer.schedule call is not in a loop and getting called repeatedly? That would explain the initial delay working but the spawn rate appearing very frequent.

Comment: Thanks! You were effectively right. I couldn't quite tell if the Timer.schedule was in a loop, so I cut and paste it into a different method. It now works like a charm. Cheers again.